# PyMongo and RaspberryPi

Tags: python, mongodb, raspberry-pi, pymongo

I have a problem with PyMongo and my raspberry pi.

When I am executing the below code I have different behaviors depending on if I run it on my laptop or on my Raspberry Pi:

```py
import ssl


def insertDB():
    import pymongo
    from datetime import datetime
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "mongodb+srv://******:*******@cluster0.nrs4u.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE )
```

When I execute it on my laptop, it writes data into my database correctly. But, if I execute the same code on my raspberry pi. I get an error on `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE`.

Note that PyMongo is installed on the raspberry.
And even there is additional code, this one is not relevant for this problem.

Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: A wild guess, but try `pip install certifi`. I dont have an rpi to test it out on,

Comment: Already installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem

```
import certifi 

ca = certifi.where()

client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "mongodb+srv://******:*******@cluster0.nrs4u.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
        tlsCAFile = ca )
```